# How to create WordArt text effects in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript

I need to add the text effects like  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNfxk.jpg using `fabric.js`

Which js I've to add?

Comment: try this http://css-tricks.com/typefacejs-a-sifr-alternative/ but i highly doubt you can do that. For that type of text , just use photoshop

Comment: But I need in PHP Fabric.js

Comment: That's not possible I guess

Comment: @BaseMPandian `No offence intended`... please take some time to understand and learn JavaScript... gain some experience... and after sometime you will realize just how challenging this problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible Pal, but you have to take a bg-image or png file some text like it.
I have edited this http://fabricjs.com/matrix-transformation/  to add a textbox(from where i can put what text i need to) dynamically on my localhost. Your task is simple just learn the Matrix and remember to put bg-image or png file in code.